# Read data from beagleboneblack in real time

Tags: c, beagleboneblack

I already have a C code that reads data from an accelerometer using I2C communication and print it in console or store it in a .txt file in the beaglebone memory. The purpose of the project is to have these data in real time in my PC to process it with other algorithms. My  question is how can I modify my C code that instead of print my data in console, send these data to the PC.

Comment: Well, what link are you going to use?  USB?  Ethernet?

Comment: I  was thinking to use USB but if Ethernet is easier so I can use Ethernet. In other words I'm looking for the simplest way @Martin James

Comment: use serial communication to transmit your data in real time to your PC.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by having the BBB log the data to a file.  After each hour of collecting data it would close the file and open a new one and continue logging.  The files were saved to a FAT32 partition that showed up on the PC when the BBB was plugged into the USB of the PC.  I could then download the log files to the PC.  This is not quite real-time, but it was close enough for me.